# External Js file generated by brunch is not working

Tags: javascript, brunch

I'm having trouble running external js from js file that is compiled by brunch.
My external js code is not invoked by the browser.
The external css compiled by brunch is fine though.

project structure:

```
+-- project_root
|   +-- public
|   +-- static
|       +-- assets
|       +-- css
|           +-- main.css
|       +-- js
|           +-- main.js
|   +-- templates
|       +-- index.gohtml
|   +-- brunch-config.js
```

my brunch-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: 'js/app.js'
    },
    stylesheets: { 
      joinTo:  'css/app.css'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    public: 'public',
    watched: ['static']
  },
  plugins: {
    cleancss: {
      SpecialComments: 0,
      removeEmpty: true
    }
  },
  sourceMaps: false

};
```

simplified index.gohtml:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>content</p>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="public/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
alert("this is my external js file")
```

app.js generated by brunch while running *brunch watch* :

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var globals = typeof global === 'undefined' ? self : global;
  if (typeof globals.require === 'function') return;

  var modules = {};
  var cache = {};
  var aliases = {};
  var has = {}.hasOwnProperty;

  var expRe = /^\.\.?(\/|$)/;
  var expand = function(root, name) {
    var results = [], part;
    var parts = (expRe.test(name) ? root + '/' + name : name).split('/');
    for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
      part = parts[i];
      if (part === '..') {
        results.pop();
      } else if (part !== '.' && part !== '') {
        results.push(part);
      }
    }
    return results.join('/');
  };

  var dirname = function(path) {
    return path.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
  };

  var localRequire = function(path) {
    return function expanded(name) {
      var absolute = expand(dirname(path), name);
      return globals.require(absolute, path);
    };
  };

  var initModule = function(name, definition) {
    var hot = hmr && hmr.createHot(name);
    var module = {id: name, exports: {}, hot: hot};
    cache[name] = module;
    definition(module.exports, localRequire(name), module);
    return module.exports;
  };

  var expandAlias = function(name) {
    return aliases[name] ? expandAlias(aliases[name]) : name;
  };

  var _resolve = function(name, dep) {
    return expandAlias(expand(dirname(name), dep));
  };

  var require = function(name, loaderPath) {
    if (loaderPath == null) loaderPath = '/';
    var path = expandAlias(name);

    if (has.call(cache, path)) return cache[path].exports;
    if (has.call(modules, path)) return initModule(path, modules[path]);

    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + name + "' from '" + loaderPath + "'");
  };

  require.alias = function(from, to) {
    aliases[to] = from;
  };

  var extRe = /\.[^.\/]+$/;
  var indexRe = /\/index(\.[^\/]+)?$/;
  var addExtensions = function(bundle) {
    if (extRe.test(bundle)) {
      var alias = bundle.replace(extRe, '');
      if (!has.call(aliases, alias) || aliases[alias].replace(extRe, '') === alias + '/index') {
        aliases[alias] = bundle;
      }
    }

    if (indexRe.test(bundle)) {
      var iAlias = bundle.replace(indexRe, '');
      if (!has.call(aliases, iAlias)) {
        aliases[iAlias] = bundle;
      }
    }
  };

  require.register = require.define = function(bundle, fn) {
    if (bundle && typeof bundle === 'object') {
      for (var key in bundle) {
        if (has.call(bundle, key)) {
          require.register(key, bundle[key]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      modules[bundle] = fn;
      delete cache[bundle];
      addExtensions(bundle);
    }
  };

  require.list = function() {
    var list = [];
    for (var item in modules) {
      if (has.call(modules, item)) {
        list.push(item);
      }
    }
    return list;
  };

  var hmr = globals._hmr && new globals._hmr(_resolve, require, modules, cache);
  require._cache = cache;
  require.hmr = hmr && hmr.wrap;
  require.brunch = true;
  globals.require = require;
})();

(function() {
var global = typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window;
var __makeRelativeRequire = function(require, mappings, pref) {
  var none = {};
  var tryReq = function(name, pref) {
    var val;
    try {
      val = require(pref + '/node_modules/' + name);
      return val;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.toString().indexOf('Cannot find module') === -1) {
        throw e;
      }

      if (pref.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1) {
        var s = pref.split('/');
        var i = s.lastIndexOf('node_modules');
        var newPref = s.slice(0, i).join('/');
        return tryReq(name, newPref);
      }
    }
    return none;
  };
  return function(name) {
    if (name in mappings) name = mappings[name];
    if (!name) return;
    if (name[0] !== '.' && pref) {
      var val = tryReq(name, pref);
      if (val !== none) return val;
    }
    return require(name);
  }
};
require.register("static/js/main.js", function(exports, require, module) {

alert("this is my external js");

});

;require.register("___globals___", function(exports, require, module) {

});})();require('___globals___');

/* jshint ignore:start */
(function() {
  var WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
  var br = window.brunch = (window.brunch || {});
  var ar = br['auto-reload'] = (br['auto-reload'] || {});
  if (!WebSocket || ar.disabled) return;
  if (window._ar) return;
  window._ar = true;

  var cacheBuster = function(url){
    var date = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
    url = url.replace(/(\&|\\?)cacheBuster=\d*/, '');
    return url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') +'cacheBuster=' + date;
  };

  var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  var forceRepaint = ar.forceRepaint || browser.indexOf('chrome') > -1;

  var reloaders = {
    page: function(){
      window.location.reload(true);
    },

    stylesheet: function(){
      [].slice
        .call(document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]'))
        .filter(function(link) {
          var val = link.getAttribute('data-autoreload');
          return link.href && val != 'false';
        })
        .forEach(function(link) {
          link.href = cacheBuster(link.href);
        });

      // Hack to force page repaint after 25ms.
      if (forceRepaint) setTimeout(function() { document.body.offsetHeight; }, 25);
    },

    javascript: function(){
      var scripts = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('script'));
      var textScripts = scripts.map(function(script) { return script.text }).filter(function(text) { return text.length > 0 });
      var srcScripts = scripts.filter(function(script) { return script.src });

      var loaded = 0;
      var all = srcScripts.length;
      var onLoad = function() {
        loaded = loaded + 1;
        if (loaded === all) {
          textScripts.forEach(function(script) { eval(script); });
        }
      }

      srcScripts
        .forEach(function(script) {
          var src = script.src;
          script.remove();
          var newScript = document.createElement('script');
          newScript.src = cacheBuster(src);
          newScript.async = true;
          newScript.onload = onLoad;
          document.head.appendChild(newScript);
        });
    }
  };
  var port = ar.port || 9486;
  var host = br.server || window.location.hostname || 'localhost';

  var connect = function(){
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':' + port);
    connection.onmessage = function(event){
      if (ar.disabled) return;
      var message = event.data;
      var reloader = reloaders[message] || reloaders.page;
      reloader();
    };
    connection.onerror = function(){
      if (connection.readyState) connection.close();
    };
    connection.onclose = function(){
      window.setTimeout(connect, 1000);
    };
  };
  connect();
})();
/* jshint ignore:end */

;
```

The app.js is  automatically filled with additional js code that I don't understand as I'm not a js expert.

I have tried this:[JS compiled by Brunch does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610591/js-compiled-by-brunch-does-not-run) still no luck.